# delete a remote branch with hg-git

Tags: mercurial, branch, hg-git

I use **mercurial** with **hg-git** extension and I can't **delete** a **remote github branch** (bookmark) with it.
I read that it was not possible with this extension,
is there any other mercurial extension or modified version of hg-git which could get the job done?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). It might be a good idea to [edit] the question afterwards so that it doesn't appear that you are asking for a tool recommendation.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to delete a git branch from the hg side of things? Or delete an hg bookmark from the hit side of things?

Comment: I have a bookmark that I have pushed to a github repo, and I'm not able to delete it from github using hg-git.

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't possible in the currently-released versions, the next feature release — probably 1.1 — [adds support for that](https://foss.heptapod.net/mercurial/hg-git/-/merge_requests/158). If you check out the `default` branch of hg-git, you can use `hg push -B somebookmark`, and use that to either only publish *that* bookmark, or delete it remotely if it doesn't exist locally.

Comment: My version of hg-git allows -B, but when I try to push a locally-deleted bookmark it fails with `abort: revision 000000000000 cannot be pushed since it doesn't have a bookmark`.